# memory access trace using pin tool

Tags: profiling, intel-pin

I just have an issue while using the intel's pin tool. I want the memory access trace of a c++ program and for that am using it. First I run c++ program (./a.out) using

```
../../../pin -t obj-intel64/pinatrace.so -- ./a.out
```

Now in the c++ I also printed the address of each variable. Now when I replace all the addresses in the file generated by pin with the actual variable name output by the file it gives me wrong sequence.

For example for a sum program where variable 'a' and 'b' are added and result is stored in 'c' and printed on console (just a small 5 lines code), In the file generated by pin 'b' exists 150 times and 'a' exists 33 times and 'c' exists 3 times. But in the code all variables are referred not more than twice. How can I get the actual memory access trace. Kindly can anyone help me please will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all surprising that memory addresses on the stack are used several times.
Consider the following code:

```
int main() {
  {
    int a = 0;
  }
  {
    int b = 0;
  }
}
```

If the assignments won't be optimized away, I can almost guarantee that the two assignments will be made to the same memory address.

Now consider the fact that before and possibly after your code executes, there's quite a bit runtime initialization, and it should be clear why what you're seeing is totally expected.

You can use the example provided in InstLibExamples/filter.cpp to see how to filter out memory tracing for certain IMGs.

Comment: there's no way to output the memory access trace of a program then?

Comment: This is a memory access trace. It just includes more than you think.

Comment: During instrumentation, you can look at TRACEs' IMG to filter out traces that belong to an image that is part of the runtime (say, libc.so). You can see an example for how to do it using InstLib in InstLibExamples/filter.cpp. Look at the InstLib/filter.cpp code to see how it's done.